# Preventing the page reload with sweetalert

Tags: jquery, alert, sweetalert

I have the sweet alert to display after the product has been removed. But, the page is reloaded with `window.location.reload();` within few milliseconds of sweetalert. how can i not reload unless i click on ok. just like normal `alert()`.

```
swal({
    title: "Product removed from your watchlist!",
    type: "success",
    confirmButtonClass: "btn-success",
    confirmButtonText: "OK!",
    closeOnConfirm: false
});    
window.location.reload();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
swal({
 title: "Product removed from your watchlist!",
 type: "success",
 confirmButtonClass: "btn-success",
 confirmButtonText: "OK!",
 closeOnConfirm: false
}, function(isConfirm){
    if (isConfirm) {     
       window.location.reload();
   } 
});
```

They have given one such example in their demo :http://t4t5.github.io/sweetalert/
Check the one which say - "... and by passing a parameter, you can execute something else for Cancel".